# Procesar los datos de entrada de un listener NetCat

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Holaa, hice  el siguiente codigo para escuchar por el puerto 9999 paquetes udp

la ip  de la maquina que corre este codigo es "192.168.200.2" auqneu lo deduciran por el codigo posterior a este. :S

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
        nc  -lvku -p 9999  
done
```

el cual mediante comandos `echo "RaspberryPi B dejo de funcionar" >/dev/udp/192.168.200.2/9999`

Bien, yo lo que queria es que ejecutandose en forma de daemon el codigo previo , cuando reciba una entrada de datos con el mensaje "RaspberryPi B dejo de funcionar" tome una serie de acciones y por ejemplo es "RaspberryPi A dejo de funcionar" tome otros; estos mensajes de entrada pueden ser mandados en cualquier momento , y bueno yo intente hacerlo leyendo cada linea y procesando su contenido pero no funciono , quiero decir, asi:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
        nc  -lvku -p 9999 | read line;
        echo "$line"
        if [ $line -eq "RaspberryPi B dejo de funcionar" ]; then
           #codigo...
        else
           #codigo
        fi
done
```

**EDICION 1 y problema**

```
#!/bin/bash

while true 
do
    nc  -lku -p 9999 | (
        read -r line
        echo "Procesando: $line"
    if [ "$line" = "RaspberryPi B dejo de funcionar" ]; then
        echo "RaspberryPi B dejo de funcionar" 
    else
        echo "ACCIONES para A"
    fi
)

done
```

Utilizando este codigo, si mando mensajes , solo recibo una vez , aunque siga mandandolos. Lo logico es que recibiera por parte del receptor, varios mensajes "RaspberryPi B dejo de funcionar"

[image: i]

Comment: Como falla? O sea, cual es el error y/o/u/e problema?

Comment: Creo que el fallo esta en `nc  -lvku -p 9999 | read line;` que no lee las líneas pues la salida de `nc` es de error.

Comment: Abre dos terminales para la prueba, vi que usaste Ctrl+Z, eso pausa la ejecución del programa. Puedes utilizar nohup para ejecutar el programa: `nohup ./receptor.sh &`. La salida estará en nohup.out

Comment: Puedes ver en otra terminal con `tailf nohup.out`.

Comment: con nohup tamb solo visualizo 1 vez.. ```root@kali:/home/kali# cat nohup.out 
Procesando: RaspberryPi B dejo de funcionar
RaspberryPi B dejo de funcionar
```

Comment: pero en la salida que ponse cuento dos veces `RaspberryPi B dejo de funcionar`.

Comment: pro que la primera es como leyendo la linea y la siguiente es un echo mio , mira mi codigo , el codigo de edicion 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes utilizar lo siguiente:

```sh
nc  -lku -p 9999 |& (
    read -r line
    if [ "0$line" = "0RaspberryPi B dejo de funcionar" ]; then
        echo "ACCIONES para B"
    else
        echo "ACCIONES para A"
    fi
)
```

ejecuta el comando y mediante una tubería procesa la salida.

**Nota:** `|&`, es para procesar la salida de error también.

**Nota:** `if [ "0$line" = "0Ras...`, la comparación es con `=` no `-eq` (que es para números) y el `0` delante del texto es para prevenir errores si `$line` está vacía.

Espero que te funcione.
Para lo de la ejecución como demonio puedes utilizar `nohup` para probar y `start-stop-daemon` para la ejecución real.

**Nuevo**

Puedes enviar comandos desde otra PC o localmente utilizando el comando:

```sh
nc -u IP PORT <<< "RaspberryPi B dejo de funcionar"
```

por ejemplo:

```sh
nc -u 127.0.0.1 9999 <<< "RaspberryPi B dejo de funcionar"
nc -u 192.168.43.2 9999 <<< "RaspberryPi A dejo de funcionar"
```

**Nota:** el parámetro `-u` es para indicar que usarás el protocolo UDP, que es el mismo por el que estás escuchando.

Comment: perfecto , solo tenia desconocimiento del uso correcto de read y como aplicarlo a mi caso , lo de control de errores me sera muy util , gracias

Comment: Si combinas `-v` y `|&`, lo verboso se pasa al `stderr`, lo cual lo hace inservible en el primer intento, ya que el proceso en segundo plano corriendo en la subshell, se gasta en leer ese registro, casi trivial.

Comment: quite el -v dado que lo usaba com prueba

Comment: Disculpa, tengo el problema de que detecta el primero pero luego si mando mas , no detecta mas mensajes, es decir , mando mensajes y recibo pues Acciones para A/b pero luego aunque mande mas mensajes no vuelvo a obtener nada de Acciones para A/B

Comment: saca ```root@kali:/home/kali# ./receptor.sh 
Procesando: RaspberryPi B dejo de funcionar
RaspberryPi B dejo de funcionar
``` y aunque le mande mas , no va

Comment: prueba `echo "your message" >> /dev/path/`. Nota el uso de **>>**.

Comment: ya lo hice , el funcionamiento es el mismo, creo que el problema esta en la parte del receptor :S

Comment: Asegúrate de que los parámetros que le pasas al comando `nc` son los correctos.

Comment: @Shockz he actualizado la respuesta para añadir un ejemplo de cómo puedes enviar mensajes: `nc -u IP PORT <<< Mensaje`

Comment: vale, pero @LeoLopez eso no solventa el problema que tengo , mandar los mensajes de esa forma no soluciona el problema que me surgio , que figura en la edicion 1 de mi pregunta, por favor

Comment: Quita el `while` el parámetro `-k` hace que se quede escuchando mensajes

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar `TCP` para poner un ciclo while alimentado dentro de una subshell:

```
$ nc -lk 9999 | ( 
while :
do
    read linea
    if [ "$linea" = "ac1" ]
    then
        echo "::::::::::: Accion1"
    else
        echo "::::::::::: Otra accion"
    fi 
done
)
```

Y en la otra puedes hacer esto:

```
$ nc 127.0.0.1 9999 <<< ac2
```

Resultando en esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema con UDP es que se te puede quedar colgado y no pasar nada a la subshell. En ese caso podríamos volver a tu `while` inicial:

```
$ while :
do
    
    linea=$(nc -luw 0 9999)

    echo linea es: $linea
    if [ "$linea" = "ac1" ]
    then
        echo "::::::::::: Accion1"
    else
        echo "::::::::::: Otra accion"
    fi 
done
```

Y ya desde la otra terminal podemos pasarle mensajes de la forma:

```
$ nc -w0 -u 127.0.0.1 9999 <<< ac1
```

**Nota**: Esto lo hago usando netcat-openbsd. Para otra versión, me parece que sólo hay que añadir el parametro `-p` para indicar el puerto.

Comment: Sinceramente no me funcionan tus codigos, en el de tcp recibo un error en la parte que envia el mensaje , recibo esto ```root@raspberrypiA:/home/pi# nc 192.168.200.2 9999 <<< RaspberryPi B dejo de funcionar
nc: port number invalid: B
``` , y respecto al udp el propio codigo del listener no me funciona no detecta lo que le mando (lo testeo mandando mensajes masivos para que alguno de los udp sea detectado), y el codigo que me facilitas para enviar el mensaje del udp tmb falla con le mismo problema que el de tcp

Comment: Entonces ha de ser por lo que expliqué en la nota. Por la versión de `netcat`. Pero también porque no pones entre comillas la cadena. Recuerda que los espacios se interpretan como comandos separados, a menos que esten entrecomillados. Ejemplo: `$ nc -u 192.168.200.2 -p 9999 <<< "RaspberryPi B dejo de funcionar"`.  O algo así. Córrelo según se indique en tu versión de netcat.

Comment: ahora si que se manda , era por las comillas; aunque la parte del receptor no funciona , y si ya he puesto  -p dado que mi version la necesita :S

Comment: Por ejemplo en el comentario de la persona de arriba , yo recibo udp pero solo una vez , luego aunque mande , no sigue digamos sacando el mensaje "de confirmacion" en base a lo que le mando

Comment: Si, pero nota como el parámetro `-k` también cambia un poco las cosas. Si haces un while y dentro le metes el comando netcat, te recomiendo no uses el parámetro `-k` porque este mantiene viva la conección a pesar de que se interrumpa. En otras palabras: 1) Si usas un while fuera, no uses el parametro `-k`, sino `-w 0` o su equivalente (como yo lo uso en mi código), 2) Si usas el parametro `-k` y luego le pasas lo que recibe a una subshell, entonces, dentro de la subshell usa un while.

Comment: Otra opción es desinstalar tu comando `nc`, y luego instalarle el openbsd para que te funcione tal cual mi respuesta, es decir: `sudo apt install netcat-openbsd`.

Comment: O no lo desinstales, sólo instala la versión de openbsd, y luego mandala a llamar con `$ nc.openbsd ... etc`

Comment: tengo el mismo problema que  comento en la otra respuesta, de hecho edite la pregunta con mi problema